# unpacking an array of arguments in php

Tags: php, arguments, iterable-unpacking

Python provides the "*" operator for unpacking a list of tuples and giving them to a function as arguments, like so:

```
args = [3, 6]
range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
```

This is equivalent to:

```
range(3, 6)
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve this in PHP? Some googling for variations of "PHP Unpack" hasn't immediately turned up anything.. perhaps it's called something different in PHP?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) to achieve that:

`call_user_func_array("range", $args);` to use your example.

Comment: This looks like an old answer - using the argument unpacking operator is probably more appropriate now, see @Salvador Dali's answer

Comment: Agree with @jgivoni.  The general trend in PHP, first seen in 7, and now PHP 8, is to move away from uncontrolled functions such as `call_user_func_array()`, `func_get_args()`, etc., in favor of the variadics operator "...".  Now ... I would be much obliged if someone could tell me how to do this in python: $m = 'getName'; $name = $obj->$m();

Answer (score 43):

In `php5.6` [Argument unpacking via `...` (splat operator)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) has been added. Using it, you can get rid of `call_user_func_array()` for this simpler alternative. For example having a function:

```
function add($a, $b){
  return $a + $b;
}
```

With your array `$list = [4, 6];` (after php5.5 you can declare arrays in this way).

You can call your function with `...`:

```
echo add(...$list);
```

Answer (score 9):

In certain scenarios, you might consider using `unpacking`, which is possible in php, is a similar way to python:

```
list($min, $max) = [3, 6];
range($min, $max);
```

This is how I have arrived to this answer at least.
Google search: `PHP argument unpacking`

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking about `($min, $max)` or `{$min, $max}`. But `list` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You should use the call_user_func_array

```
call_user_func_array(array(CLASS, METHOD), array(arg1, arg2, ....))
```

http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array

or use the reflection api http://www.php.net/oop5.reflection

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function add(int ...$arr) {           // typehint ready
    return array_sum($arr);
}

var_dump(add(1, 2, 3, ...[1, 2, 3])); // int(12)
```

Another example with ... - operator.
RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics