# pass variables in array as function paramaters?

Tags: php, class

I have a function that does something similar to this:

```
function load_class($name){
  require_once('classes/'.$name.'.php');
  return new $name();
}
```

what I want to do is modify it so I can do something like this

```
function load_class($name, $vars = array()){
  require_once('classes/'.$name.'.php');
  return new $name($array[0], $array[1]);
}
```

The general gist of it is.

I want to be able to pass in an array of values that, gets used as the parameters for the class.

I dont want to pass in the actual array.

is this possible?

Comment: While the answer you accepted is certainly correct, I would encourage you anyway to look into class autoloading as indicated by bharath. From the code you provided it looks like you're overcomplicating things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call functions this way with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), but in the case of a class constructor, you should use [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php):

```
class MyClass {
   function __construct($x, $y, $z) { }
}


$class = new ReflectionClass("MyClass");

$params = array(1, 2, 3);

// just like "$instance = new MyClass(1,2,3);"
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($params);
```

Your code might look like this:

```
function load_class($name, $vars = array()){
  require_once('classes/'.$name.'.php');
  $class = new ReflectionClass($name);
  return $class->newInstanceArgs($vars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's called var args and you want to unpack them. http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php. Check out the examples... [unpacking an array of arguments in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294313/unpacking-an-array-of-arguments-in-php).

See Also [How to pass variable number of arguments to a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to load classes then you could use `__autoload` function

more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.)

Comment: Or even better using spl_autoload_register(). +1