# PHP - Pass array as variable-length argument list

Tags: php, arrays, function, variadic-functions

I have really simple problem in my PHP script. There is a function defined which takes **variable length argument list**:

```
function foo() {
  // func_get_args() and similar stuff here
}
```

When I call it like this, it works just fine:

```
foo("hello", "world");
```

However, I have my variables in the array and I need to pass them "separately" as single arguments to the function. For example:

```
$my_args = array("hello", "world");
foo(do_some_stuff($my_args));
```

Is there any **do_some_stuff** function which splits the arguments for me so I can pass them to the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Use this answer. This is much more accurate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34049110/2147023

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unpacking an array of arguments in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294313/unpacking-an-array-of-arguments-in-php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

- [`ReflectionFunction::invokeArgs(array $args)`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.invokeargs.php)

or

- [`call_user_func_array( callback $callback, array $param_arr)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: +1 for `Reflection`s. Although it's like an overkill here, but it's always cool to deal with them!

Answer (score 6):

Well you need `call_user_func_array`

```
call_user_func_array('foo', $my_args);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's exactly what I need. However, I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for `call_user_func_array()`.

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Usage:

```
$my_args = array("hello", "world");
call_user_func_array('foo', $my_args);

// Equivalent to:
foo("hello", "world");
```

Comment: This is far better than to use Reflection in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you are looking for `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's exactly what I need. However, I can accept only one answer.

Comment: Just accept the one that either gives the most required detail, or the earliest one :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Isn't this what you want?

edit
ah... ok... how about this:
[Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Nope. I have already read this. All the functions are supposed to work _inside_ my "foo" function. I need to split the arguments before they are passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the code of `foo()` it should be easy to solve this in just one place.

```
function foo()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    if(count($args) == 1 && is_array($args[0]))
    {
        $args = $args[0]
    }
    // use $args as normal
}
```

Comment: This not works if he wants to pass an array (for real) as first argument.

Comment: No, it does not work if there's only one argument and that argument is supposed to be an array. If there's more than one argument then they're all left alone.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not recommended at all, but just showing a possibility :

Using `eval`

`eval ( "foo('" . implode("', '", $args_array) . "' )" );`

Comment: I know it's only "showing a possibility", but still... it's eval. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but it still comes up as the first search result - so here is an easier way;

```
<?php
function add(... $numbers) {
    $result=0;
    foreach($numbers as $number){
      $result+=intval($number);
    }
    return $result;
}

echo add(...[1, 2])."\n";

$a = [1, 2];
echo add(...$a);
?>
```

Source:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-142